# Bitbucket clone error Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, clone

I am a but new to `bitbucket`. I was able to add/ commit and push to the source tree on `bitbucket`. The problem I have is that I am unable to `clone` the project. I receive the following error.

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:miloyj/fl1proj.git MYProj
Cloning into 'MYProj'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '124.102.103.3' to the list of known hosts.
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I also created a private key using the command `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, and pasted the public-key on the `Access Key` section under the `BitBucket` settings page. However, the error still persists.

Can someone help me sort this.

Comment: Is your key located in a non-standard path (i.e.: not `~/.ssh/id_rsa`)? What is the output of `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org -i path_to_key`?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a valid IP for Bitbucket. Where did you get that?